# Pq não estou conseguindo criar uma função dentro de uma classe com o nome de do array list de um método da classe em php?

Tags: php, classes

Por que não estou conseguindo criar uma função dentro de uma classe com o nome de do array list de um método da classe em php?

```
function $this->info[0](){

}
```

Comment: O nome da função é `$this->info[0]()` ? tem detalhes faltando na sua pergunta.

Comment: Cara, isso aí só com scaffold. O PHP é dinâmico, mas nem tanto.

Comment: Para você não ficar confuso com os negativos, entenda que o fato de que a pergunta não está clara e fora do escopo do site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tem como fazer isso em PHP. O máximo que pode ser feito é uma chama dinâmica de métodos, mas não uma declaração:

```
 class Aluno {

      public function __construct($nome)
      {
         $this->nome = $nome;
      }
      public function nome()
      {
           return $this->nome;
      }
 }
```

A chamada poderia ser feita assim:

```
$aluno = new Aluno('Wallace');
$aluno->{$this->info[0]}();
```

O que você está tentando fazer, no seu exemplo, causa um erro de síntaxe.